# Adding SSL to Heroku free plan

Tags: heroku, ssl

I have a 3rd party SSL certificate I want to install, which the dashboard suggests I can manually configure for free, but that I would need to set it up manually unless using the paid ACM. However when doing this I eventually get told I need to upgrade to a paid plan.

Is it at all possible to install an SSL certificate on a free plan?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This site is focused on Salesforce, its platform, and related technologies. Unless you're asking about Heroku (which Salesforce aquired 9 years ago), the more appropriate place for this question would likely be [so] or going through your product's official support channels. In any case, you'll need to provide a lot more background and detail.

Comment: I've edited to clarify that this post is about Heroku. You could further improve it if you [edit] to share which documentation you referenced and the details of the messaging you receive.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed about Heroku, I was linked directly here from the Heroku help page so assumed it was a dedicated sub-forum. Not too sure what other information I can provide in this case, it's a question directly about Heroku's features rather than a technical issue, but the site isn't clear about where else to raise this so would appreciate any guidance

Comment: I am going to unilaterally reopen this question because I believe close votes were cast before it was clarified that this question is about Heroku, which is on topic. @Cameron it would help if you made an [edit] to show the exact documentation you are referencing and the steps you took when you were advised to upgrade to a paid plan.

Comment: My close vote was partly due to the lack of clarity and information described above. The other part was that OP's account is unregistered, which I believe to have a significant chance to "ask-and-run". I had expected precisely 0 response.